# Use two controller in the same page

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I'm currently making my first app on Ionic2 and I'm a little confused with Typescript. I would like to display a popup and a modal on the same page: I have to import ModalController and AlertController from 'ionic-angular'. I can use only alerts with the following code:

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }
}
```

or only modal by using the following code:

```
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalPage } from './modal-page';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }
}
```

but when I want to use the two, I would have used two constructors but it's impossible... 
What is the correct way to use these two components?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject multiple providers in a constructor..
Do this:

```
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController,public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
```